# Database is locked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I fix a database lock..since my test isn't passing - it's making a bunch of tests in the same category fail. thanks!

```
1) UsersController GET 'edit' should have a link to change the Gravatar
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "name", "salt", "updated_at") VALUES ('2011-05-29 03:47:07.510067', 'mberman84@gmail.com', 'fc70fcb4b094b388d87c5054ed9b0bfa06f53431d44c527e852c5bdffd3a0fa8', 'Matthew Berman', NULL, '2011-05-29 03:47:07.510067')
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:128:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is due to a Rails Console Session being open. To get around this in the future be sure to `bin/rails console -s` and when accessing the SQLite 3 DB ensure to exit any console sessions.

Comment: In case anyone else was a little confused/ignorant of the rails options, he means script/rails console -s.  The -s is for "sandbox", and means any changes are rolled back when you exit.  I guess this means the console does not need a write lock on the database; though why it would ever keep a write lock inbetween commands is mysterious to me.