# Integration test error with capybara for ajax call with rails 3.2.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

Here is a integration test case with capybara in rails 3.2.12. `click_link 'New Log'` is an ajax call. However the page opened starts with $() and has a bunch of js escape like \n and \log-log.

```
it "should work with link on show customer_comm_record page" do
      visit customer_customer_comm_records_path(@cust)
      #visit customer_customer_comm_record_path(@cust, @crecord)
      click_link @crecord.id.to_s     
      click_link 'New Log'
      save_and_open_page
end
```

We also tried to wrap the case with `describe "", :js => true do`, how there is an error saying

```
`An error occurred in an after hook   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked:`
```

There is no error out of code execution. What's wrong with the rspec case? Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have the Rails console open when you see this?

Comment: I did not try rails console. Is there something new from rails console for the error?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165889/database-is-locked

Comment: Closed up the rails s window and the database lock is the same. The db lock error only appears with :js => true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your server is locking the database so that the test cannot clean up after it has run.

When you use Capybara without JavaScript the tests and server are all running in a single process and thread. This means they can share the same database connection and transaction. This means that RSpec can use a simple database transaction to roll back changes at the end of the test and why you don't see any lock contention between test and server.

When you run with `:js => true` things are a little different, the server starts up in a separate thread or process to your tests so they will each be using a separate database connection and transaction. This means that the database transaction strategy that RSpec uses by default to clean up won't work. It is also causing lock errors in your case.

The Capybara [readme](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup) talks about this problem and recommends [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem as an alternative in this situation. You will need to configure database cleaner to use the truncation strategy rather than transactions

Comment: see detailed explanation at http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/