# ActiveRecord SQLite3 BusyException "cannot open savepoint"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, sqlite

I am using Rails3 with FactoryGirl and RSpec for tests. Some tests started to fail with the following error:

> Failure/Error: let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
>
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>
> SQLite3::BusyException: cannot open savepoint - SQL statements in progress: SAVEPOINT active_record_1

This only happens if I run the whole test suite. If I run tests for only 1 file then it passes without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use lazy version `let(:user)` instead `let!(:user)`. There might be a problem in heavy DB load due to multiple calls with `let!`.

Another possible reason of lock is [open console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154664/ruby-sqlite3busyexception-database-is-locked). Or the way, how Capybara works with [multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307742/integration-test-error-with-capybara-for-ajax-call-with-rails-3-2-12).

Guess, the easiest solution would be to [add some timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78801/sqlite3busyexception).

Comment: The timeout did the trick, but it feels like a hack and the tests are now slower. Would like to see a real fix. By the way, I need the let!

Comment: To say something more specific the code of tests (and perhaps controller and model) are needed.